# Binding a facesmessage to a tag in xhtml page

Tags: java, jsp

I want to bind a facesmessage to a specific component in my xhtml page.
My facesmessage looks like this:

```
ctx.addMessage("newAdmin:email", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No email!", "You should enter a email"));
```

So that the clientId is "newAdmin:email".
My xhtml page looks like this:

```
<h:body>
<h:form class="text-left" id="newAdmin">
    <h1 class="centerTxt">Televic Login</h1>
    <h:messages class="error" globalOnly="true" />
    <label>Email</label>
    <h:inputText class="form-control" id="lg_username" value= "#{userController.email}"></h:inputText>
    <h:message for="email"></h:message>
    <h:commandButton class="btn btn-success" value="Login" action = "#{userController.login()}"></h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

When I set the clientId to "null", it binds the message fine to the global messages tag, but the binding to a specific message tag won't work.
What's wrong? How can i find the right clientId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any component in your JSF file with the email id. The `for` attribute of the `h:message` component attaches the message to the component that has the corresponding id. It seems that it should be:

```
<h:message for="lg_username"></h:message>
```

and in your Java code:

```
ctx.addMessage("newAdmin:lg_username", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No email!", "You should enter a email"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect answer :)